# Python: Group by for filter

Tags: django, django-models

I have a bill and customer service. I will to get users who buy something in last day.

How I can get user count with bill model?

I will to get count of **distinct** user of this query:

```
recived = Bill.objects.filter(status=2,pay_status=True)
```

And `Bill` model:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20,default="")
    desc = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True,default="")
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_tax = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_discount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_payed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pay_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    transport = models.ForeignKey(Transport,null=True,blank=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address,null=True,blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product,related_name='Bill_product',through="Bill_product")

    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Can you show your model? Without knowing how the `Bill` models relates to the user one it's hard to know how to count it.

Comment: @cms_mgr Absolutely. sorry, i update question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use a custom SQL query for this if Bills were likely to become very large. Something like:

```
from django.db import connection


sql = """
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
    FROM your-app-name_bill
    WHERE status=2
    AND pay_status=True;
"""

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.fetchall()
```

Alternatively, you could populate a list with the user IDs, then call set() on the list to make them distinct:

```
users = [x.user_id for x in Bill.objects.filter(status=2, pay_status=True)]
distinct_count = len(set(users))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use count method on your query set as below
   `Bill.objects.filter(status=2,pay_status=True).count()`

refer here .. [count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count)

Comment: I want to find distinct user count dude. For example 5 users buy 10 product. I want to get *5*

Comment: This will count bills rather than users.